# PynamoDb - Increment operation

Tags: python-3.x, pynamodb

Is there a way to do the below code snippet using `pynamodb`?

```
dynamoDB.updateItem({
  TableName: "Users",
  Key: { "UserId": { S: "c6af9ac6-7b61" } },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":inc": {N: "1"} },
  UpdateExpression: "ADD loginCount :inc"
})
```

I can see it is supported, as per the [test here](https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/blob/fd24c67a452b2ff2ed6357221c46257069e2402a/tests/test_expressions.py#L468) and the [doc here](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/updates.html#update-expressions) , but when I try to do an `add` operation on a numeric field as shown below, it throws `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add'`  exception.

`test_table.balance.add(int(dep_amount))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add` operation is an update action, so it should be included in a list of actions passed to `test_user.update` as follows:

```
test_user.update(actions=[User.balance.add(int(dep_amount))])
```

The pynamodb docs include a section on [Updating Items](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=update#updating-items).

Comment: is it possible to do the update `raw` way just like in the old `update_items` style by providing the attribute name and value?